# Unresolved external symbol error for overloaded constructor

Tags: c++, oop

Actually I've been searching my error and i found tons of solutions but they couldn't fix my problem and probably this is easy but i can't handle...

```
/* header */
class EmployeeRegister
{
private:
    EmpReg *Emp;
public:
    EmployeeRegister(int,int);
};


/* cpp file*/
EmployeeRegister::EmployeeRegister(int a,int b)
{
    cout << "Result  : " << a+b << endl;
}


/* in main file*/
EmployeeRegister Sub(1,1);
```

and when i do this or something like this i get :

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: 
   __thiscall EmployeeRegister::EmployeeRegister(int,int)" 
   (??0EmployeeRegister@@QAE@HH@Z)
```

Actually I'm sure this is easy but what am I missing ?

EDIT : It's fixed , linker couldn't find my .cpp file.

Comment: Is the `.cpp` file included on the link line?

Comment: Are you sure you've added the .cpp file to the project, so the linker finds it?

Comment: yes u right linker can't find my .cpp file thanks alot...

Comment: @SashaVolkoff: Please explain what IDE and what compiler you use, how you initiate the compilation (build) of the project.

Comment: @pts it was QT5 and gcc

Comment: There is a [faq entry](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1782465) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your non-main .cpp file is listed in the project (or in linker command-line) so that it can be properly linked with your main.cpp

Answer (score 1):

As you are a newbie,

Please mention how do you build the project.
You should compile both main.cpp and EmployeeRegister.cpp and link both main.o and EmployeeRegister.o files.

`g++ -c Main.cpp
g++ -c EmployeeRegister.cpp
g++ -o binaryname Main.o EmployeeRegister.o`

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.